# Background image isnt fixed on Mobile

Tags: css, shopify

i'm working on my clothing brand shop (SHOPIFY) and added a background image.
On Desktop it looks perfect, exactly how i wanted. But on mobile, the image is distorted and even if the CSS code is on `background-attachment: fixed;` the image scrolls with the products and the other content.

Website: [www.hyghassociation.org](http://www.hyghassociation.org)

Here is my full code:

```
    body,
html {
  background: url({{ 'background.jpg' | asset_url }});
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
body {
    
    background: url({{ 'mobile_background.png' | asset_url }});
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Please try mobile view on real phone not F12 view on computer, there its somehow fine..

Comment: mobile phones often switch this off because it is very annoying sometimes - and the only way I know to get around it is with javascript

Comment: IOS does not support background-attachment: fixed see [link]https://caniuse.com/?search=background-image and the background image will appear zoomed-in/fuzzy.

Comment: I dont understand.. on https://spiritbysiberia.com/ it also works on mobile... why can they do this?